# Jquery find children object contains and replace text

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='foo'>
    <a><b>a</b></a>
    <a><b>b</b></a>
    <a><b>c</b></a>
</div>

$('#foo:contains("b")').text('bb');
```

I need to find children obj's content and replace something else
but above code will replace everything inside of id foo.

what I need is if inside of #foo contain 'b' find that children element and replace different string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:last` selector

`#foo:contains("b")` - selects elements containing the specified string

`#foo :contains("b")` - selects children containing the specified string

`#foo :contains("b"):last` - selects last children containing the specified string

```js
$('#foo :contains("b"):last').text('bb');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo'>
  <a><b>a</b></a>
  <a><b>b</b></a>
  <a><b>c</b></a>
</div>
```

**For multiple** use `:last-child`

```js
$('#foo :contains("b")').find(':last-child').text('bb');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo'>
  <a><b>a</b></a>
  <a><b>b</b></a>
  <a><b>c</b></a>
  <a><b>b</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: what if there is another <a><b>b</b></a> and I want to replace it too

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector `#foo b:contains("b")` instead, to select a `b` child of `#foo` which `contains` b:

```js
$('#foo b:contains("b")').text('bb');
console.log($('#foo')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo'>
    <a><b>a</b></a>
    <a><b>b</b></a>
    <a><b>c</b></a>
</div>
```

If you don't know the tag name, and need to find an element which contains a text node containing `b`, it's a bit more complicated, filter for elements which contain at least one `childNode` which is a text node which has `b`:

```js
const $allElementsThatContainB = $('#foo *:contains("b")');
const $elementsWhichImmediatelyContainB = $allElementsThatContainB.filter(function() {
  return [...this.childNodes].some(node => node.nodeType === 3 && node.textContent.includes('b'));
});
$elementsWhichImmediatelyContainB.text('bb');
console.log($('#foo')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo'>
    <a><b>a</b></a>
    <a><b>b</b></a>
    <a><b>c</b></a>
</div>
```

If you only want to find elements whose innerHTML is *exactly* `b`, it's easier:

```js
const $allElementsThatContainB = $('#foo *:contains("b")');
const $elementsWhichImmediatelyContainB = $allElementsThatContainB.filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML = 'b';
});
$elementsWhichImmediatelyContainB.text('bb');
console.log($('#foo')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo'>
    <a><b>a</b></a>
    <a><b>b</b></a>
    <a><b>c</b></a>
</div>
```